# Video created in FFMPEG on YouTube doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, video-processing, video-capture, duration

There is a problem when working with FFMPEG and then uploading to YouTube.

I have a video that is 4:15 long (255 seconds). When I create such a video in Adobe Premiere and upload it to YouTube, everything is fine. The problem occurs when I create such a video in FFMPEG. Before the HD versions are processed (>= 1080p) the video works fine, but when the HD versions appear, its duration on the scrollbar becomes 4:00 (240 seconds). If you go to the end of the video at 4:00, it continues to play for another 15 seconds.

Here is an example of such a video clip: https://youtu.be/G_tMctEklM4

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxWs5.png

I would be grateful for your help.

**UPD**

I think I figured out what the problem was.

I took 5 video files of 25 seconds each and merged them. The resulting file is ~125 seconds long, I uploaded it to YouTube - everything is fine. Then I tried to build my project - again, problems. Apparently, the problem is that I merged 42 files: 2 files for ~20 seconds and 40 files for 5-6 seconds. These are not integers, here are some of the files:

06.143000, 05.983000, 06.488000, 06.018000, 05.809000

So, I understand FFMPEG rounds them down to integer number, and due to the fact that there are a lot of such files - 42, so there is a shift of 15-20 seconds (about 0.5 seconds from each file). But what to do with it I still do not understand.

Related topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/e1o3hv/ffconcat_filter_with_millisecond_precision_how/f8qvztl/

and this (???): [ffmpeg - avoid duration approximation of generated files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856784/ffmpeg-avoid-duration-approximation-of-generated-files)

Comment: I suspect the last video frame is at 4m00s. Share your full ffmpeg command and log.

Comment: This is a lesson on learning English in Bulgarian.

Project: https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/project.bat
Log: https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/lesson-3-bg-BG-white-male.txt
Result (~16 MB): https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/lesson-3-bg-BG-white-male.mp4

Comment: And source (~11 MB): https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/lesson-3.zip

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow.

Comment: @Gyan, thank you! I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: In the result, the video stream duration is `268.966667` and audio is `283.189002`. In your begin and words formation commands, add `-loop 1 -framerate 60` before the image input, and `-shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M` before the output filename.

Comment: @Gyan, you're amazing! It really works. Thank you so much! 

I am facing a new problem. I create 42 video files without re-encoding (using -shortest ... -c copy), these files are created correctly. Then I merge them together (using -copy) and the output file is 4:53 instead of 4:43.

Comment: I do the following:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -i 1.png -i 1.mp3 -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -c copy 1.mp4`
...
`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -i 40.png -i 40.mp3 -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -c copy 40.mp4`

and

`ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: warnings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZNup.png

Comment: Share the two generated word MP4s.

Comment: @Gyan, https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/concat_copy.zip (68 MB)

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful (source): https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/concat_copy_source.zip (8 MB)

Comment: @Gyan, I can't do it without you.

Comment: Seems fine. ffmpeg shows the duration for the inputs to be 6.34s and 5.93s. For output, it shows video to be 12.293s and audio to be 12.288.

Comment: @Gyan, let's start over. First, I combine the MP3 and PNG (84 files) with each other to get 42 short MP4 files. Then I merge the resulting 42 files with the concat demuxer (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1). As a result, I get a file that is 4:53 in length instead of 4:43. This file: https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/new/wrong-4-min-53-sec-result.7z My code: https://pastebin.com/6d1HtY7Q My source: https://turism.ru/ffmpeg/new/project.zip

Comment: That's too big. Let's start with a small test case that shows this issue.

Answer (score 0):

after making your ffmpeg video, process it using video edit on your computer and later compress it to the bits you want, it will uppload on youtube, its a long process a bit but you get the results am using it now for a month, i had the same problem too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).